# Determining the outcome of an encounter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I generally have no idea how to complete the following bullet points. Help would be appreciated!!! I have put the code I have got so far below but like I said, have no idea how to incorporate this into my code. Thanks sooooo much.

• The differences between the strength attributes for the two characters is calculated

• This difference is divided by 5 and then rounded down to create a ‘strength modifier’

• The process is repeated for the skill attribute to create a ‘skill modifier’

• Each player throws a 6 sided dice.

• If the scores on both dice are the same, no changes are made

• If the scores are not the same, the player with the highest score adds the ‘strength
modifier’ to the strength value and the ‘skill modifier’ to the skill value for their
character

• The player with the lower score on the dice subtracts these modifiers from the
strength and skill values for their character

• If a skill value becomes negative, then it is stored as zero

• If a strength value becomes zero or negative, then the character dies.
The program should:

• Allow the user to input the strength and skill for two characters.

• Display the outcome of the encounter using the process above.
Design an algorithm to describe this process. Write, test and evaluate the code."""

```
import random

def character_attributes():
    initial_value = 10
    character1_strength = initial_value + (random.randint(1,12) // random.randint(1,4))
    character1_skill = initial_value + (random.randint(1,12) // random.randint(1,4))
    character2_strength = initial_value + (random.randint(1,12) // random.randint(1,4))
    character2_skill = initial_value + (random.randint(1,12) // random.randint(1,4))

    print("Character 1 now has a strength attribute of {0}".format(character1_strength))
    print("Character 1 now has a skill attribute of {0}".format(character1_skill))
    print("Character 2 now has a strength attribute of {0}".format(character2_strength))
    print("Character 2 now has a skill attribute of {0}".format (character2_skill))

    myfile = open('character_attribute_data.txt', 'w')
    myfile.writelines('Character 1 has a strength attribute of : ')
    myfile.writelines(str(character1_strength))
    myfile.writelines('\n')
    myfile.writelines('Character 1 has a skill attribute of: ')
    myfile.writelines(str(character1_skill))
    myfile.writelines('\n')
    myfile.writelines('Character 2 has a strength attribute of : ')
    myfile.writelines(str(character2_strength))
    myfile.writelines('\n')
    myfile.writelines('Character 2 has a strength attribute of : ')
    myfile.writelines(str(character2_skill))
    myfile.close()

character_attributes()

def dice_roll(number):
    if number == 12:
        number = random.randint(1,12)
        print(number)
        return number
    elif number == 6:
        number = random.randint(1,6)
        print(number)
        return number
    else:
        number == 4
        number = random.randint(1,4)
        print(number)
        return number

 print("12 sided")
 print("6 sided")
 print("4 sided")

rolls = {4: [], 6: [], 12: []} # dictionary to hold rolls
while True:
    roll = int(input("Which dice would you like to roll? --> ")) # store die size
    rolls[roll].append(dice_roll(roll)) # roll and add to dictionary
    doRepeat=input("Go again? --> ")
     if doRepeat == "no":
        break 
     print(rolls)
```

Comment: I think this is best approached by using classes. Having two functions to carry all that work is pretty difficult to maintain.

Comment: I'm fairly new to computing and my teacher at school is not very good so I'm  struggling a bit so I decided to come to this website for help instead of snide comments :)

Comment: I don't want people to do all the code but just want a few tips or hints or something

Comment: To stop this from cascading into an argument: refer to my first comment. A `class` will help you do this. See the lone answer below. A class is basically a framework of sorts. Think of it as a template. You can store default stats there, default name, etc. Quite honestly, classes is one of the first things you should learn if you're using Python to code a game-type program with as many variables as the above. Also, if tips and reviews are what you need, we have CodeReview.SE for that.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm just worried cause I have to do this for gcse

Comment: What is this task? There seem to be several people asking very similar questions, including [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22302215/how-do-i-change-a-sum-for-string-for-it-to-work), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773543/how-do-i-loop-a-code-until-a-certain-number-is-created), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622908/i-tried-this-in-python-2-4-but-it-is-not-working-properly) more-or-less identical question.

Comment: Well, OP did say it was for GCSE. If I'm not wrong, that's like the GED. Homework, basically, if I'm right.

Comment: Yeah, GCSEs are exams taken here in the UK at age 15-16.

Comment: @Nanashi please watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0 and stop writing classes :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code to work from:

Do note that if the initial strengths differ by less than 5 (57.4% chance), or if they change to become different by less than 5 in the course of the game (unknown probability, but quite likely), the game will continue forever (`mod_strength` will always be 0).

```
import random

STRENGTH = (10, 22)
SKILL    = (10, 22)

class Character:
    def __init__(self, name, strength=None, skill=None):
        self.name     = name
        self.strength = strength or random.randint(*STRENGTH)
        self.skill    = skill    or random.randint(*SKILL)
        self.roll     = None

    def throw(self):
        self.roll = random.randint(1, 6)

    def mod_strength(self, amt):
        self.strength = max(0, self.strength + amt)

    def mod_skill(self, amt):
        self.skill = max(0, self.skill + amt)

    def is_dead(self):
        return self.strength == 0

    def __str__(self):
        return(
            "{}: str {} ski {}"
            .format(self.name, self.strength, self.skill)
        )

def calc_modifier(val1, val2, div_by):
    return abs(val2 - val1) // div_by

def main():
    ch1 = Character("Conan")
    ch2 = Character("Xena")

    while True:
        ch1.throw()
        ch2.throw()
        print("Roll!  {}, {}".format(ch1.roll, ch2.roll))

        if ch1.roll > ch2.roll:
            print("  {} wins".format(ch1.name))
            dir = 1
        elif ch1.roll == ch2.roll:
            print("  Tie...")
            dir = 0
        else:
            print("  {} wins".format(ch2.name))
            dir = -1

        strength_mod = calc_modifier(ch1.strength, ch2.strength, 5)
        ch1.mod_strength(strength_mod * dir)
        ch2.mod_strength(strength_mod * -dir)

        skill_mod = calc_modifier(ch1.skill, ch2.skill, 5)
        ch1.mod_skill(skill_mod * dir)
        ch2.mod_skill(skill_mod * -dir)

        print("  {}, {}".format(ch1, ch2))

        if ch1.is_dead():
            print("{} is the victor!".format(ch2.name))
            break
        elif ch2.is_dead():
            print("{} reigns supreme!".format(ch1.name))
            break

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted classes might be good.  But if it is too early in your learning to get your head around classes let me just modify your dice_roll function so it is easier to understand and extend

```
def dice_roll(numberOfSides):
    if numberOfSides not in set([4,6,12]):
        print ("Valid die size is either 4, 6, or 12")
        return 'Invalid'
    number = random.randint(1,numberOfSides)
    print(number)
    return number
```

and then handle the empty return

```
if dice_roll == 'Invalid':
    do_something
```

You can code it like that without the else statements because the same operation is performed on the die no matter the size.  This saves you a lot of headache wondering later why you define different outcomes for different die size.

One thing about writing code - I am going through it right now is it is always better when you go back through it a second time.